# How can I look through my camera in the Scene view in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Without going to game view. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is it also possible you did try something before you asked this? And what exactly did you do?

Answer (score 54):

Actually, it's GameObject Menu->Align View To Selected.

Comment: I just love how your answer has so much more points than the other same answer posted months before. Being concise goes a long way I guess. Upvoting both of you tho.

Comment: And I love that I can get a little pingback on an answer from 11 years ago! Cheers.

Comment: @bokibeg Except... the other answer was incorrect for about 5 years until someone else edited it.

Comment: This solution doesn't really work well because 1) it doesn't match the camera's properties such as "Field of View", and 2) it doesn't update automatically as you move the camera. @Bunny83' solution below is much better, imo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665081/1262685

Answer (score 35):

I think I know of a solution for you. . .

In Unity:

- Select the Camera (GameObject) that you would like to look through while in the Scene view.
- Then go to the "GameObject" Menu and select "Align View to Selected."

I hope this helps.

Comment: Contrarily， I want to get the camera position values that used by the #scene  window to apply into the inspector . What should we do?

Answer (score 4):

Why not drag your gameview below or above your sceneview. That way you can see both windows. I always work that way ;)

Comment: Nice tip! Thx for that. So simple that I've never thought about doing that... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Click on your camera object from hierarchy and click on GameObject->Align View to Selected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Unity Pro (which makes render textures available), constructing a quick editor script to handle this should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I think what he's describing is the ability to have the "Scene" window be from camera and therefore have it that changes to perspective using the alt key could be automatically adjusting the keys. Is that correct?

In other words, the ability to animate the camera from the scene window with the camera as your view by using alt to drive value changes. That would be helpful.

3D programs like Maya and Max let you select the camera as your view and by having the camera selected and autokey on will adjust the key values based on changes you're making in your viewport.

But bowditch's suggestion is the next best thing. Change the scene view window to what you want, then select the camera object and in the GameObject pulldown select "Align with View" and the camera will snap to that. Then set a key on the camera object.

Answer (score 2):

Go to hierarchy bar in Unity Editor

- Press F Key
- Double click on object/ main camera

To view objects in different angels you can externally apply rotation, transformation (move) in any of x,y,z and for more details or less details you can zoom in-out with ease of mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the camera in the hierarchy and then click on the rotation button , after that you can change camera directions in the x,y,z planes and see the camera align in a small sqaure in the scene view , Therefore no need for game view

Hope that helps